Index in database of MariaDB-server gets corrupted
I am running Mariadb-servers in Docker and in the last 3 weeks, 3 of those servers encountered the same problem. All over sudden the servers stoped working with error-messages like this for many different tables in different databases:
Writing to DB failed: 1034 (HY000): Index for table 'historical_data' is corrupt; try to repair it. 

After restarting the Container, the server did not work anymore, it just restarted over and over again with the following error log:
240409 09:16:16 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /config/databases
2024-04-09  9:16:16 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.13-MariaDB-log source revision a24f2bb50ba4a0dd4127455f7fcdfed584937f36 as process 7028
2024-04-09  9:16:16 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 6635)
2024-04-09  9:16:16 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 200 (was 200)  table_cache: 397 (was 400)
2024-04-09  9:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
2024-04-09  9:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-04-09  9:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2024-04-09  9:16:16 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /var/tmp (disabling future attempts)
2024-04-09  9:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2024-04-09  9:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 67108864, chunk size = 67108864
2024-04-09  9:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-04-09  9:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=25675814987,25675814987
2024-04-09  9:16:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Retry with innodb_force_recovery=5
2024-04-09  9:16:19 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
2024-04-09  9:16:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-04-09  9:16:19 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2024-04-09  9:16:19 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2024-04-09  9:16:19 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-04-09  9:16:19 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2024-04-09  9:16:19 0 [ERROR] Aborting
240409 09:16:19 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
240409 09:16:21 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /config/databases

To solve the problem, I had to start the servers with "innodb_force_recovery = 5" and export all data to a fresh instances of those containers.
What could be the reason for this behaviour? I've been running this servers and other ~30 similar ones now for at least 2 years. The last update was about about 3 months ago to version 10.6.13. There was still enough disk space available. The hardware the servers are running on are Industrial PCs with armv7hf-Architecture with 32 GB SSD and 2 GB RAM. Thanks for your help!
Here my mysql.cnf:
## custom configuration file, please be aware that changing options here may break things

[mysqld_safe]
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
max_connections     = 200
connect_timeout     = 5
wait_timeout        = 60000
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 128
sort_buffer_size    = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size      = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
binlog_format=mixed
event_scheduler=ON

collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
character-set-server = utf8mb4
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'


#####Namesauflösung der verbindenden Clients ausschalten####
#Dadurch wird der Verbindungsaufbau deuuutlich beschleunigt#
skip-name-resolve

######Einsetllung zur Kompatibilität zwischen den Betriebssystemen
######Sorgt dafür, dass alle Buchstaben immer klein geschrieben werden
lower_case_table_names = 1

#
# * MyISAM
#
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched. On error, make copy and try a repair.
myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
key_buffer_size     = 8M
#open-files-limit   = 2000
table_open_cache    = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
concurrent_insert   = 2
read_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
# Cache only tiny result sets, so we can fit more in the query cache.
query_cache_limit       = 128K
query_cache_size        = 8M
# for more write intensive setups, set to DEMAND or OFF
#query_cache_type       = DEMAND
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /config/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# we do want to know about network errors and such
log_warnings        = 2
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file = /config/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan

#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#log_slow_admin_statements
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#report_host        = master1
#auto_increment_increment = 2
#auto_increment_offset  = 1
log_bin         = /config/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index       = /config/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
# not fab for performance, but safer
#sync_binlog        = 1
expire_logs_days    = 1
max_binlog_size         = 100M
# slaves
#relay_log      = /config/log/mysql/relay-bin
#relay_log_index    = /config/log/mysql/relay-bin.index
#relay_log_info_file    = /config/log/mysql/relay-bin.info
#log_slave_updates
#read_only
#
# If applications support it, this stricter sql_mode prevents some
# mistakes like inserting invalid dates etc.
#sql_mode       = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
# you can't just change log file size, requires special procedure
#innodb_log_file_size   = 50M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completion
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size     = 16M




could be an already fixed bug. I'd drop the index, start and updated container and try again.

Additional DB information request from your primary server, please.
OS, Version?
cores on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions to consider.

Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE,
top -b -n 1  for most active apps,
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage,
ulimit -a       for list of limits,
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count,
df -h  for Used - Free space by device,
df -i  for inode info by device,
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:,
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.
